# Nesed IF statements with default of 'x'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What I want to understand is how do I make this happen in one line of code?:

```
=IF(H15 = True,"H15 is the best plan"), IF(H16 = True, "H16 is the best  plan"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the IFs (ie do not be premature in closing the parentheses):

```
=IF(H15=True,"H15 is the best plan",IF(H16=True,"H16 is the best plan","x"))
```

Add more IF clauses if required immediately before `"x"` - and add closing parentheses to suit.